Check & Set Status of Automatic Reply Feature in Outlook VBA
I am using this code in Outlook VBA to check and set automatic Reply Feature Status. When I activate the feature in outlook manually and check the status via VBA, then i am getting the expected value everytime.
But when i set the value via VBA, i can check also via VBA that it was set to True for example but the function looks not activated in outlook. I tried to send an e-mail from another account to see if i receive an automatic reply, but i got no automatic reply.
Sub CheckStatus()
    MsgBox Check_Out_Of_Office()
End Sub

Sub ActivateStatus()
    OutOfOffice True
End Sub

Function Check_Out_Of_Office() As Boolean
    'Checks to see if out of office is already enabled
    On Error GoTo eh
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim oStores As Outlook.Stores
    Dim oStr As Outlook.Store
    Dim oPrp As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Set oNS = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oStores = oNS.Stores
    For Each oStr In oStores
    If oStr.ExchangeStoreType = olPrimaryExchangeMailbox Then
    Set oPrp = oStr.PropertyAccessor
    Check_Out_Of_Office = oPrp.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661D000B")
    End If
    Next
    Exit Function
eh:
        MsgBox "The following error occurred: " & Err.Description
End Function


Sub OutOfOffice(bolState As Boolean)
'Calling this with a state of True enables out of office and calling it with a state of False disables out of office
On Error GoTo eh
    Const PR_OOF_STATE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661D000B"
    Dim olkIS As Outlook.Store, olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    For Each olkIS In Session.Stores
        If olkIS.ExchangeStoreType = olPrimaryExchangeMailbox Then
            Set olkPA = olkIS.PropertyAccessor
            olkPA.SetProperty PR_OOF_STATE, bolState
        End If
    Next
    Set olkIS = Nothing
    Set olkPA = Nothing
Exit Sub
eh:
    MsgBox "The following error occurred: " & Err.Description
End Sub


I found this code under: https://4sysops.com/archives/automate-out-of-office-messages-in-outlook-with-visual-basic-for-applications-vba/
I am having exchange account using Microsoft 365
I don't want to install any external libs like redemption which are not included in Outlook.

While PR_OOF_STATE can be used to read the OOF state, setting it requires SetUserOofSettings EWS method. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/hh532556(v=exchg.80)
